# Extract coordinates of ROC curves of auroc function PLSDA R

Tags: r, roc

I am using the following codes to calculate area under the ROC curve for my PLSDA model:

```
auroc.plsda<-auroc(plsda.fert, newdat=X,outcome.test = as.factor(Y),plot = TRUE, roc.comp = 1:19)
```

with 'plsda.fert' is the name of the model object.
with this code, I can see the ROC curve plotted, but I want to customize the plot (title, color...), which I need to extract the coordinates. I have been looking for this but could not find the way.
Does anyone on our forum know how to do this. Please

Thank you,
Phuong

Comment: Have you considered using a separate library for ROC analysis?

Comment: @Calimo: I used mixOmics R package for my PLSDA model calibration, and this 'auroc' function is introduced in the manual of that package to calculate ROC curve. I do not know if I can apply other functions to calculate ROC curve on the model object produced by mixOmics plsda. What would you recommend in this case? Thanks